# PHP..How to print month only from a date variable

Tags: php, date, echo

I have a date variable like 10-25-1998 and I only want to echo 10. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks...

```
$dateString=date("m-d-Y", mktime(0,0,0,10,25,1998));
echo date('m', $dateString); // not working here....will print out 01
```

Comment: Your question title asks for month, but you want to echo 25 which is a date... which do you want to echo?

Comment: totally my bad.....see update..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

strtotime will not recognize "m-d-Y" format, so the only way to get the month out of that string is to just parse it yourself, knowing that it's the first value in your string:

```
$dateString=date("m-d-Y", mktime(0,0,0,10,25,1998));
$t = explode('-',$dateString);
echo $t[0]; //month
echo $t[1]; //day
echo $t[2]; //year
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$tomorrow = mktime(0,0,0,01,25,1998);
echo "Month is ".date("m", $tomorrow);
```

For more info look here: [PHP Date() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_date.asp)

Answer (score 1):

```
$first2chars = substr($tomorrow, 0, 2);
```

picks the first 2 characters of the string $tomorrow

take care

Answer (score 0):

You may want the [getdate](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php) function:

```
$today = getdate();
echo $today["mon"];
```